# Video won't load on my page

Tags: html, css, video

For some reason when I put the code below, nothing happens, the video won't show. What is weird is that everything worked fine about 5 days ago. Last night my chrome just like auto updated itself, maybe it is because of that? Please any suggestion. My code:

```css
video {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>    
    <video autoplay loop>
        <source src="" type="video.mp4">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</header>
```

Comment: Is the path of video.mp4 defined correctly? I.E. is the videofile located where you tell your DOM it is?

Comment: Remove the incorrect `<source src="" type="video.mp4">`.

Comment: Yes, everything is in the right place, I've removed the incorrect code , still nothing.

Comment: Are you getting console errors? Is this all of your code or is this little header part surrounded by more html? Same goes for the CSS, is this all the CSS you've got?

Comment: No console errors, I've got just a basic bootstrap layout and this is only what is in the body. As for CSS Ive got body{margin:0; padding:0;} and the video above.

Comment: Really strange. I made a little example that's working for me. Is it working for you too? http://jsfiddle.net/5bg4ckah/

Comment: Have you tried checking if the video is accessible ex: http:yourdomain/video.mp4, to see if it works?

Comment: Have you also tried adding a CSS position, whether it is fixed, relative or else?

Comment: @SteynvanEsveld just a black screen

Comment: Also tried adding position nothing seems to be working...

Comment: I don't think it's because of Chrome since I develop mostly in Chrome and the last project I did involved a fullscreen video looping, and it is working fine still. Something else must be causing this. Could you setup a quick DEV url or JsFiddle for us to see, thanks

Comment: @Ognjen I work in Chrome too (version 45 on OS X right now) and my fiddle works perfectly. Seems to be a problem with your local computer I suppose. You could download Firefox and check if it works in there.

Comment: Reinstalled chrome, works perfectly, I still don't know what was the problem but nevermind.